# Input.GetKeyUp() only sometimes gets used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm working on a 2d platformer game in Unity. I want to be able to jump sideways and vertically, however jumping vertically somehow doesn't seem to work. the worst part is that the sound plays, so i concluded that the condition gets met, but doesn't jump still.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    if (jumpSpeed< 10f)
    {
        if (Bossfight.bossfightStarted) jumpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 8;
        else jumpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 4; //Double jump speed
    }
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
{
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
    if (Bossfight.bossfightStarted) jumpSpeed = 7f;
    else jumpSpeed = 5f;
    //Sound
    if (!isPlaying)
    {
        hunterJump.Play();
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is this code?

Comment: provide complete context of code.

Comment: Conext would be great!!